# Entity Framework throws an error when executing a lambda expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core

I have this piece of code for fetching and filtering results of products from a database:

```
if (userParams.MinPrice > 0 && userParams.MaxPrice != 999999999) 
{
    products = products.Where(p => (p.Price >= userParams.MinPrice) && 
                                   (p.Price <= userParams.MaxPrice));
}
```

This gets executed successfully when only the `userParams.MinPrice` is provided but fails when `userParams.MaxPrice` is provided.

The error that I get is this.

> An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
>
> System.InvalidOperationException: An exception was thrown while attempting to evaluate a LINQ query parameter expression. To show additionalinformation call EnableSensitiveDataLogging() when overriding DbContext.OnConfiguring.
>
> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.
>
> at lambda_method(Closure )
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionVisitors.Internal.ParameterExtractingExpressionVisitor.Evaluate(Expression expression, String& parameterName).

Does anyone know the solution to this? Please help

Comment: Max price is null. if (userParams.MinPrice  != null && userParams.MinPrice > 0 && userParams.MaxPrice != null && userParams.MaxPrice != 999999999)

Comment: The MaxPrice is not null since it has the default value of 999999999 if the user does not provide their own value.

Comment: You must be setting it to null after it is set to default value.  The default value is not shown.

Comment: I have debugged, stepped through and confirmed that it is not null when passing it to the where clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty simple, your error explains it. `userParams.MaxPrice` is null. So you need to add null checking to it. A simple way would be to change your query to:

```
if (userParams.MinPrice > 0 && userParams.MaxPrice != null && userParams.MaxPrice != 999999999) 
{
    products = products.Where(p => (p.Price >= userParams.MinPrice) && 
                                   (p.Price <= userParams.MaxPrice));
}
```

Though depending on your logic you may need to change things up slightly. The key point is to not assume that a property has a value, if it's nullable, then you need to first validate it's not null then check it.

Should also add that you could in theory do `userParams.MaxPrice.GetValueOrDefault() != 999999999` assuming that this is a nullable int or something like that.

Comment: The userParams.MaxPrice has a default value of 999999999 if the user does not provide their own value.I have been debugging the code and the userParams.MaxPrice is not null.

Comment: Previously this was working but on the next day it started showing the error.

Comment: Debug and step through. You'll see that your assumption about your userParams object must be incorrect. The only way to get the error you listed is to have a null value.

Comment: I have debugged and stepped through each step and checked the value of maxPrice and indeed it is not null. if the user does not provide their own value the default value is applied. when the user provides their value i have  confirmed that it is shown while i debug. i don't know whats the real cause of this problem.

Comment: @StephenMutua if it's not `userParams.maxPrice` then it's something in `userParams`. You can only get a `NullReferenceException` if something is null and you try and access it. Even if it's not the specific thing I mentioned in my answer, the gist is the same, you need to know 100% that every property being accessed will never be null or you need to validate in code that it's not null before trying to access it.

Comment: I have done everything I can. The worst thing is right now even the minPrice is also showing the error and it was not showing as I posted my first question. Could it be something to do with entity framework on my machine?

Comment: I have finally got where the problem was. I had to step through each process that leads to checking the value of MaxPrice and found a previous if statement that changed the value of products thus assigning the MaxPrice as null.